# Sharepoint: How to prevent a user from closing a webpart

Tags: security, sharepoint

I see that the close or hidden options can be set for a webpart, but it seems anyone can edit those settings when in edit mode.  Do you use item level security?  If so, what are the specific steps to accomplish this in 2010?

Comment: The user should still be able to move the web parts around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend removing the user's permission to edit the page.  This should prevent them from going into edit mode, and thus prevent them from closing web parts.

Comment: I don't think that will work because I still want the user to be able to move the web parts around